# Can't Find Xbox One Media Player

Tags: xbox-one

Where is the Media Player is on Xbox One? I've downloaded the October update and searched online. I've tried installing it from the Store and couldn't find it there.  I also can't find it on the console. [Most places](http://www.cinemablend.com/games/Xbox-One-October-Update-Rolls-Out-With-Full-DLNA-Server-Support-67887.html) seem to suggest that I need to download it first.

Comment: I've got it in my apps store. If you got to the New Releases section of the app store and go right to the end, it's there.

Comment: It's called Media Player Preview on mine.. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @ImClarky - thanks that did it. I had not seen the ellipsis to view more New Releases. Once you mentioned scrolling to the end, I realized there must be more.

Comment: @ImClarky - Set it as an answer, so the question can be marked completed.